# How do I programmatically change the Size Class variation on an NSLayoutConstraint in Swift

Tags: swift

I can change simple [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/)s in Swift which were set up in a storyboard. For example this is a width constraint from my storyboard

```xml
<constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="600" id="EGo-Al-B35"/>
```

and here's how I change it in Swift (I'm doing this in a UIViewController's subclass's viewDidLoad override):

```swift
let newVaue:CGFloat = CGFloat(414) // Actually some working out here
self.constraintOutlet.constant = newVaue
self.constraintOutlet.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

But not all the constraints I want to update are that simple. Specifically some use Auto Layout's Size Classes to provide revised values for the constraint in landscape orientation. Here's how an example looks in my storyboard

```xml
<constraint firstItem="kcH-BX-CS6" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="nvV-Xd-fnh" secondAttribute="bottom" id="I6B-Lp-edd">
    <variation key="heightClass=compact" constant="250"/>
</constraint>
```

How would I change that variation's constant from Swift code?

Comment: Am I understanding it right, that you basically want to change the constant `250` to another value between the top of the first view and the bottom of the second view? If so, you can just change your constraint variable's `constant` property, no `setValue` needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the question. I'm after how to set the `constant` with key "heightClass=compact" in the variation. How do I do that? I only want to do it once, in viewDidLoad, not on orientation change so I think I want to change the constant embedded in that size class variation.

Comment: Sadly I have found some evidence that this is not possible. It the list of "points that are often skipped over in tutorials" at the start of his article [Fear and Loathing in Auto Layout: Programmatic Constraints](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2015/07/auto-layout-programmatic-constraints.html) Anthony Levings notes that "There are no addConstraintForSizeClass() methods"